# HANA attribute view search properties

Tags: search, view, attributes, hana

I tried searching a lot but couldn't find ways to implement use cases of attribute view column search properties.

You can configure [search properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pojTO.jpg) for applicable columns in attribute view.

But what I donot understand is how to utilize these properties. SAP HANA search developer's guide doesn't tell exactly how this can be used. Is it possible to directly expose these properties to Odata or search UIs? If yes, how?

Any pointers to this would be very helpful.

Thanks,
Anup